# Can Spark code in Scala be converted to Java?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have source that uses Apache Spark. The source is written in Scala and I want to convert it to Java.

Is it possible to convert to Java from all Scala source?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer here is going to be: Technically yes, but not with a result that you'll like.

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve? No dependency on anything Scala? No trace of anything Scala? Be able to continue development in Java, of code that was originally written in Scala?

Comment: I've edited the title to reflect the actual content of the question. The original "can Scala code be translated to Java" is way too generic and does not apply to the specific context of the question.

Comment: @maasg but now the title talks about Spark code and the question about code using Java, and it is not at all clear what should get converted. Going to vote for closing the question.

Comment: The question is clear to me: **"I have source that uses Apache Spark. The source is written in Scala and I want to convert it to Java."**  The question had a poorly chosen title, but the content was explicitly asking about converting spark code from Scala to Java. I guess we answer to the question body and not the question title, right? In which case the question is still valid.  @user1371662  As question owner, what do you think?

Comment: @JensSchauder this is a good discussion on the title topic: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254216/should-i-edit-titles-which-have-nothing-to-do-with-the-actual-problem

Comment: @maasg I have no problem with title editing, but the title you created didn't match the question. Then the question got edited until it matched the new title, all this without any input of the OP. I'd give you at least a 50% chance that the question as it is written right now is not what the OP was wondering about.

Comment: @JensSchauder I went to see the edit history and the sequence of events is: the question got edited several times, then the title changed to match the question. Looking at the original version, I still think the essence of the question has been preserved. Could you have a look at the history log and tell me what you think?

Comment: @maasg I did just that with my previous comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65877/discussion-between-maasg-and-jens-schauder).

Answer (score 3):

**No**. The Spark Scala API is different from the Java API.

tl;dr;

Although one could do tricks to compile/decompile or have some IDE do the translation, the resulting code will not work in Spark.

One of the reasons is that the Spark Scala API makes use of implicit conversions to enable type-dependent functionality that is not available in the Java API, where the use of explicit classes is required.

A simple example:

### Scala

```
val pairs = words.map(w => (w,1))  // count here is of type RDD[(String,Int)]
val counts = words.reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

### Java

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
  public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) { return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1); }
});
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = pairs.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer>() {
  public Integer call(Integer a, Integer b) { return a + b; }
});
```

Note how the Java counterpart needs to use specific methods (`map` in Scala vs `mapToPair` in Java) and specify a given class (JavaPairRDD) to gain access to the specific pair functions, while in Scala that's not required.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Currently Spark (till version 1.1) provides a Java version for most of it's API/sub-projects, but not all. GraphX Java API is not supported. So if your Scala code is using graphx libraries then it may not work in Java unless you write custom glue code.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html

Even if you manage to decompile your Scala class files into Java you may not able to execute the Java code if your program semantics are not wrong. I would recommend you learn the Java API and then rewrite your Scala code in Java. This will also give you a better understanding of the Spark API, which is essential if you want to write your own Spark programs in the future.

Comment: I'd actually recommend to learn the little Scala that's needed to write Spark jobs.

Comment: Yes, I agree, learning Scala is the best solution. Moreover, you also need to just know very little Scala to get started with the Spark Scala API.  I specifically didn't make that recommendation because some may see that as a forcing a solution. I personally have moved away from Java and use it only when absolutely necessary (which is seldom).

Answer (score 0):

Compile sources to .class files (or download it if avaliable) and give a try to decompile it.

Here is one of such tools with wiki how-to:

https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no such tool that converts Scala source to Java.